# Nuance of waiting

Tags: word-usage

I wrote this sentence -

> *These new mode of exchange is fast, but lacks the **nuance** of waiting for the letter to come.*

I believe I haven't used properly the word "nuance". Comments please.

Comment: Here is your comment, take it: (╯°□°)╯︵ [comment].

Comment: I would use *small pleasure* rather than *nuance*, e.g. *This new mode of exchange is fast, but lacks the small pleasure of awaiting the letters.*

Comment: It eliminates the pleasure of anticipation?

Comment: You are saying that "waiting for the letter" is a "nuance".  I'm not in a position to determine if that is true, but if the "new mode of exchange" does not have this "nuance", the statement is correct.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of interpreting too deeply, I'm guessing you're saying the speed of email might be fast, but snail mail has it's virtues.  "Nuance" is a fairly neutral word, but I think you're wanting to show a positive aspect of hand delivered mail (esp from a friend or loved one).  The problem is I don't think the reader knows where you are going.  Consider the following, which makes the point more clear:

- The advent of fast email has removed from society many positive nuances of hand delivered mail.
- The new mode of exchange is fast, but lacks many virtues of hand delivered mail.  These include the anticipation and excitement of waiting, the feeling of opening the envelope - like opening a gift - the smell of perfume, the tangible sense of relationship, etc.)

Of course, you may be saying that "waiting is a virtue".  In that case, perhaps "the virtue of waiting" would be a phrase that might convey to reader the direction you are going.